# mysqli multi query not woking

Tags: php, mysql

Hi guys I have this part of a code:

```
foreach($cartItems as $item){
    $sql .= "INSERT INTO order_items (order_id, product_id, quantity) VALUES ('".$orderID."', '".$item['id']."', '".$item['qty']."');";

    $newstock = $item['stock']-$item['qty'];
    $sql1 .= "UPDATE product SET stock='".$newstock."' WHERE ID='".$item['id']."';";
}
// insert order items into database
$insertOrderItems = $conn->multi_query($sql);
$updateProductQty = $conn->multi_query($sql1);
```

and I am having problem about updating a table "product".. the first query is 1 and is ok, but sql1 output is OK but nothing happens, I tried to update this query manually in phpmyadmin and it works there.. Do you see anything what I dont? Thanks

edit: so it should look more like this?

```
        $conn->begin_transaction(MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_WRITE);

             foreach($cartItems as $item) {


                    $newstock = $item['stock']-$item['qty'];
                    $stmt = $conn->prepare('update product set stock = ? where ID = ?');
                    $stmt->bind_param('ii',$newstock,$item['id']);
                    $stmt->execute();
            }
$conn->commit();
    $conn->close();
```

this?

Comment: First, enable error checking: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: If I had to guess (and I have to, because you didn't give us any proper debugging information) I'd say that you might be getting some unexpected syntax errors because you're concatenating your query text together with the variables, instead of using proper parameterisation. Doing that also potentially leaves you vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks, so fixing it will be a double bonus. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli.

Comment: If you're going to use `multi_query` why not execute all the queries at once? Additional notes. You really shouldn't use `multi_query` it opens you to huge security holes. Your `insert`s can be done with one, just comma delimit the values.

Comment: You would be better off running 2 `->query()` inside a transaction, as these 2 database changes are very dependant upon BOTH completing or NEITHER completing

Comment: @user3783243 no, there are two multi_query statements, so $sql is executed, followed by $sql1. Two separate executions. However I hadn't considered the loop...so actually multi_query _is_ needed for that reason. I retract my earlier comment. But _two_ multi_queries? Not really necessary if $sql and $sql1 were simply concatenated. A transaction would be a sensible idea though, disregarding the rest of it. multi_query is a bad idea in general. P.S. Moving the execution into the loop (without changing anything else) would cause chaos as the earlier queries would be executed many times over.

Comment: @ADyson Oh, yes, I didn't intend for that. Just change to`$sql = ` and `$conn->query($sql);` etc for the `1`.. Also `$item['stock']-$item['qty']` is not needed. Mysql can do math.

Comment: so guys the error mysql gives me is this "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"

Comment: ___Commands out of sync___ Because you dont process the _possible_ results out of the first multi_query, the second one probably fails for that reason. Basically multi_query is just to much hassle to use properly

Comment: And as far as I know if the second query in a 2 query multi_query fails the first one will not roll back, so you would need this wrapped in a transaction anyway

Comment: so this will be better?? <code>$stmt = $conn->prepare('update product set stock = ? where id = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('ii',$newstock,$item['id']);
$stmt->execute();<code> and this should be in foreach??

Comment: yes that sort of thing, but also wrapped in a transaction so that if any individual query fails, you can roll back.

Comment: see edit pls.. is that how it should be?

Comment: You need the `order_items` insert as well and http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php.

Comment: See also [The manual for Begin Transaction](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php) and associated commit and rollback processing

Comment: am I getting closer?